# Substituição em Massa em XML

Tags: xml, regex

Bom dia!

Tenho um programa que checam alguns sinais, porém no código é indicado apenas a qual sinal deve aparecer, então devo aplicar as informações especificas que devem ser checadas. Porém fazer manualmente estas substituições leva muito tempo então gostaria de substituir em massa.

Meu código atual:

```
<comment>Check sinal P1R#</comment>
```

Substituir para:

```
<comment>P1R#</comment>
<capltestfunction title="RUN INSPECTION" name="RunInspection">
    <caplparam type="string" name="InspName" />
</capltestfunction>
<capltestfunction title="ADD IMAGE TO REPORT" name="AddInspectionImageToReport" />
<capltestfunction title="CHECK MESSAGE" name="CheckStepResultCameraText">
    <caplparam type="string" name="StepName">TM_IN023_1</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="string" name="ExpVal">STEP</caplparam>
    <caplparam type="int" name="ContainsExpVal" />
    <caplparam type="int" name="TolerateSimilarChars">1</caplparam>
</capltestfunction>
```

Não consegui substituir normalmente pois o conteudo é muito extenso. Estou aprendendo a programar ainda então preciso de um help!

Obrigado!

Comment: O que é "Check sinal" ali vai um +, -? você quer substituir tudo que esta e cima pela parte debaixo, isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo Guilherme lautert ! Gostaria de substituir tudo que esta em cima pelo debaixo. Esse Check sinal P1R# é apenas um comentario descrito o que devera ser checado que no caso seria o sinal "P1R#". Na parte de baixo se encontram os steps que uso para esse teste especifico. Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usar expressões regulares para fazer *parsing* e transformação de XML [não é uma boa idéia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/664577). O seu problema demanda ambas as coisas. A ferramenta a ser utilizada precisa primeiro encontrar *tags* `comment` dentro do documento original e depois substituí-las pelo fragmento desejado (com variações dinâmicas conforme o conteúdo da *tag* original).

Para esse tipo de transformação vale a pena utilizar uma ferramenta capaz de lidar com as idiossincrasias do XML. O bom e velho [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) costuma ser suficiente para esse tipo de coisa.

Eis uma *stylesheet* que resolve o problema da pergunta:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <!-- Identity transform -->
   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="comment">
       <comment><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(), 'Check sinal ')" /></comment>
       <capltestfunction title="RUN INSPECTION" name="RunInspection">
           <caplparam type="string" name="InspName" />
       </capltestfunction>
       <capltestfunction title="ADD IMAGE TO REPORT" name="AddInspectionImageToReport" />
       <capltestfunction title="CHECK MESSAGE" name="CheckStepResultCameraText">
           <caplparam type="string" name="StepName">TM_IN023_1</caplparam>
           <caplparam type="string" name="ExpVal">STEP</caplparam>
           <caplparam type="int" name="ContainsExpVal" />
           <caplparam type="int" name="TolerateSimilarChars">1</caplparam>
       </capltestfunction>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

#### [Veja funcionando no XSL Transform](http://xsltransform.net/gWEamKH)

---

As primeiras quatro linhas declaram uma *stylesheet* cuja saída é um XML bem formatado, identado e sem espaços desnecessários entre os elementos.

O primeiro *template* é o "*template* identidade" que simplesmente copia o conteúdo original para a saída.

O segundo *template* - mais específico do que o primeiro e portanto com maior prioridade - substitui *tags* `comment` por novos fragmentos compostos de:

1. Outra *tag* `comment` contendo o pedaço de texto após a *string* `Check Signal` na *tag* `comment` original:

   ```
   <comment><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(text(), 'Check sinal ')" /></comment>
   ```
2. As *tags* fixas do tipo `capltestfunction` e `caplparam` que você deseja incluir.

A partir desse exemplo você pode construir transformações mais complexas sem depender de expressões regulares que vão se tornando mais e mais frágeis e ineficientes conforme a complexidade do problema aumenta.

Comment: Obrigado pela força Anthony Accioly! vou tentar fazer aqui!